# Drawing Graphs from json data in Python

Tags: python, json, graph-visualization

I have a json dataset containing a list of objects as below:

```
[{
    "id": "b3654874a300f0f0dd4e8d28a651a3a5",
     "Interfaces": [
         1,
         2
     ]
 },
{
"id": "d7993235f3c34a1a8c7201846a3d87c6",
            "Interfaces": [
                3,
                4,
                5
            ]
}]
```

In this data, the each of the ids in the "Interfaces" list depict the nodes of a graph and the list depicts the connectivity between them, (for example, the list [1,2] in the first object depicts a connection between node 1 and node 2). I want to plot these automatically based on such a structure. Any library that allows me to do this programmatically, preferably in python.

It could also be a flowchart. So, any library that can create a flowchart in python is also viable.

Any help is really appreciated.